# how to set "phyDataRate" in omnetpp.ini

Tags: c++, omnet++

i am new in castalia. I've designed a routing protocol with name "myRouting". omnetpp.ini file is below. how to set "phyDataRate" ? can you help me write a complete omnetpp.ini for run my routingProtocol???

```
[General]
#Network Parameters
include ../Parameters/Castalia.ini
include ../Parameters/MAC/CSMA.ini
sim-time-limit = 300s
SN.field_x = 200
SN.field_y = 40
SN.numNodes = 20
SN.deployment = "[0]->center"

SN.node[1..19].xCoor = uniform (10,200,0)
SN.node[1..19].yCoor = uniform (5,40,0)

SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.collectTraceInfo = true

SN.node[*].Communication.MACProtocolName = "Mac802154"


SN.node[*].Communication.RoutingProtocolName = "myRouting"
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.netBufferSize = 1000
SN.node[0].Communication.Routing.isSink = true

SN.node[*].ApplicationName = "ThroughputTest"
SN.node[1..15].Application.packet_rate = 1
SN.node[*].Application.constantDataPayload = 50

SN.wirelessChannel.onlyStaticNodes = true
SN.wirelessChannel.sigma = 0
SN.wirelessChannel.bidirectionalSigma = 0
SN.wirelessChannel.pathLossExponent = 2.0

SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.RadioParametersFile = "../Parameters/Radio/CC2420.txt"
SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.mode = "normal"
SN.node[0..19].MobilityManagerName = "NoMobilityManager"
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You need to set phyDataRate for which module? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I've designed a routing protocol with name "myRouting".I want to run my own routing module. I used the "Mac802154" as a Mac protocol. but i don't know how to set the "phyDataRate" and "phyBitsPerSymbol" in omnetpp.ini.

Comment: I assume you mean the parameters in the MAC. You set them as any other parameter in Castalia. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I've written a simple routing protocol. The nodes are periodically hello packed are send, and the neighboring table and routing table are updated, and packets are passed to higher layers. I wrote the omnetpp.ini file to use this protocol and verify that it is correct. In the case of the "Mac802154" as a Mac protocol, I do not know how to set the parameters. And if I change the Mac layer, I will not see the output. Can I help you where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set these parameters as you set any other parameter in the MAC module.

```
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.phyDataRate = 1024
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.phyBitsPerSymbol = 2
```

It is not clear from your description what the problem is. Is it that you don't know how to set parameters in general? Something specific to these two parameters? In any case, all the Routing module things you mention are irrelevant to this question.

Finally, I notice that you do not use the latest Castalia version (I can tell from the MAC module name you are using). It's a good idea to use the latest version (found in GitHub).